# looping through each word in string and converting to a link returns the first value as undefined

Tags: jquery

Edit my title if it stinks, I had a hard time figuring out a good title for my problem.

I am basically taking a string like

```
See Good-By
```

and converting each word into a link and putting back into a string. The result looks like

```
<a href"#">See</a> <a href="#">Good-by</a>
```

My code works fine except for some reason the first value always returns as undefined, yet is catches all the words in the string just fine. So in this case there should be 2 loops since there are only 2 words, but it loops 3 times and the first one being undefined.

**HTML**

```
<span class="definition">See Good-by</span>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.definition').each( function(p) {
    var c;
    var result = $(this).text().split(' ');
    $.each(result, function(i) {
        if (result[i] != '') {
        var link = ' <a href="/dictionary/word/' + result[i] + '/">' + result[i] + '</a>';
        c += link;
        }
    })
    $(this).html(c);
})
```

So the result is

```
undefined See good-by.
```

See and Good-by are links as they should be and `undefined` is just text. Not sure whats going on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Initialize `c = ''` that's the problem in the code. Else the value of c will be `undefined`. that is what you are getting as `undefined`. The code snippet is attached.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.definition').each(function (p) {
                var c = '';
                var result = $(this).text().split(' ');
                $.each(result, function (i) {
                    if (result[i] != '') {
                        var link = ' <a href="/dictionary/word/' + result[i] + '/">' + result[i] + '</a>';
                        c += link;
                    }
                })
                $(this).html(c);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <span class="definition">See Good-by</span>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: OMG I didn't see that, and it's sad because I know that too lol thanks